# Jquery Mobile theme samples with small fonts

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, sample

I am looking for a theme which should be smaller fonts, smaller list boxes (less height), should give more compact style than what is available on jquery mobile. It is too big of size for each of items on themeroller for jquery mobile

Comment: you need to create custom theme, take help from themeroller to change values, or change the css directly in the custom theme.

Comment: @Sheetal, This much thought thru :). I was looking for any place where there are css already available.... Problem with changing the css is that you can miss at a few places and it will just mess up the entire page...